# HtmlUnit on Moodle: FileUpload fails despite success message

Tags: java, file-upload, moodle, htmlunit

I try to upload a file to a moodle2 container. This is done via yui. To skip this stuff I disable java script in my WebClient (browser) to get the "noscript" elements. After analysing these I get to a page where the [filepicker.php](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/repository/filepicker.php) of moodle is called.

The page looks like this.

```
<form action="http://demo.moodle.net/repository/filepicker.php?ctx_id=41&amp;itemid=861552155&amp;env=editor&amp;course=2&amp;maxbytes=67108864&amp;areamaxbytes=-1&amp;maxfiles=-1&amp;subdirs=1&amp;sesskey=chtRoKYBlC&amp;action=browse&amp;draftpath=%2F&amp;savepath=%2F&amp;repo_id=3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:inline">
    <label>Attachment: </label><input name="repo_upload_file" type="file"><br>
    <input name="action" value="upload" type="hidden"><br>
    <input name="draftpath" value="/" type="hidden"><br>
    <input name="savepath" value="/" type="hidden"><br>
    <input name="repo_id" value="3" type="hidden"><br>
    <input value="Upload this file" type="submit">
</form>
```

Complete case against demo.moodle.org (manually create Folder with Name "Test" in Mooodle-Course 'My first course' id=2 first):

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlFileInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSpan;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class MoodleUpload {

    /** Instance of WebClient */
    private static final WebClient browser = new WebClient();

    /** Current HTMLPage */
    private HtmlPage currentPage;

    public MoodleUpload(){

        //intialize WebClient
        browser.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        browser.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        browser.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        browser.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        browser.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        browser.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

        try{
            login();            
            currentPage = (HtmlPage) browser.getPage("http://demo.moodle.net/course/view.php?id=2");
            modifyFolder(getFolderByName("Test"));

        } catch (Exception e){
             Logger.getLogger(MoodleUpload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }

    }

    //perform login on moodle
    private void login() throws Exception{
        currentPage = (HtmlPage) browser.getPage("http://demo.moodle.net/");

        //get login-Form, fill in required fields and perform click
        ((HtmlTextInput) currentPage.getElementById("login_username")).setValueAttribute("manager");
        ((HtmlPasswordInput) currentPage.getElementById("login_password")).setText("sandbox");

        List<HtmlSubmitInput> inputs;
        inputs = (List) currentPage.getByXPath("//form/div/input[@type='submit']");
        inputs.get(0).click();
    }

    //finds link to folder with given name
    private String getFolderByName (String name) throws Exception{
        List<HtmlSpan> spans;
        spans = (List) currentPage.getByXPath("//a/span[@class='instancename' and text()='"+name+"']");


        System.out.println(((HtmlAnchor) spans.get(0).getEnclosingElement("a")).getHrefAttribute());

        return ((HtmlAnchor) spans.get(0).getEnclosingElement("a")).getHrefAttribute();
    }

    //trys to upload a file to a moodle folder
    private void modifyFolder(String path) throws Exception{

        //disable javascript to get noscript elements
        browser.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        currentPage = (HtmlPage) browser.getPage(path);

        //click 'edit settings'
        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors;
        anchors = (List) currentPage.getByXPath("//ul/li/p[@class='tree_item leaf']/a[text()='Edit settings']");
        currentPage = (HtmlPage) browser.getPage(anchors.get(0).getHrefAttribute());

        //get file uploader
        List<HtmlElement> up;
        up = (List) currentPage.getByXPath("//noscript/div/object");        
        currentPage = (HtmlPage) browser.getPage(up.get(0).getAttribute("data"));

        //get "add file"-Page
        List<HtmlElement> elements;
        elements = (List) currentPage.getByXPath("//div[@class='filemanager-toolbar']");
        currentPage = (HtmlPage) browser.getPage(((HtmlAnchor) elements.get(0).getFirstChild()).getHrefAttribute());
        elements = (List) currentPage.getByXPath("//a[text()='Upload a file']");
        currentPage = (HtmlPage) browser.getPage(((HtmlAnchor) elements.get(0)).getHrefAttribute());

        //get file upload form
        elements = (List) currentPage.getByXPath("//form");
        HtmlForm uploadForm = (HtmlForm) elements.get(0);

        HtmlFileInput fileInput = uploadForm.getInputByName("repo_upload_file");

        fileInput.setValueAttribute("file:///F:/Test.xlsx");
        fileInput.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

        //submit
        List<HtmlSubmitInput> inputs;
        inputs = (List) currentPage.getByXPath("//form/input[@type='submit']");
        currentPage = inputs.get(0).click();

        System.out.println(currentPage.asText());


    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        MoodleUpload tl = new MoodleUpload();
    }
}
```

If I check the current page I get a success message from moodle. But the file is not in the destinated container. I tried several modifications to my code and to the action parameter of the form corresponding to the 'documentation' of filepicker.php to no avail. If I fill out the form in Firefox, everything works fine. If I skip the setValue-Call, I also get a failure message. So something seems to happen.

Maybe this is associated to the additional hidden fields? Any help is appreciated. I would also use javascript and the yui-functionality, if this would be a feasible solution.

Comment: Can you post a complete case against moodle.org/demo?

Comment: I posted the complete case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in my moodle installation. Unfortunately this doesn't do the trick on demo.moodle.net. What I do is simple: I get the HtmlSubmitInput with the id "id_submitbutton" (=save) from the edit page. After uploading the file as I have shown, I just call click() from this submit. After that, the file is transfered from moodle draft to manager.

Answer (score 0):

Is is strange that JavaScript needs to be disabled to be able to upload a file.

Anyhow, with real Chrome:

1. Go to http://demo.moodle.net/course/modedit.php?update=1&return=1
2. Click 'Add'
3. 'Upload a file'
4. Upload actual file
5. 'The file has been uploaded successfully'
6. Refresh the page (http://demo.moodle.net/course/modedit.php?update=1&return=1)
7. "No files available"

So, how one can check if the file is correctly uploaded? and is there another way to upload a file with JavaScript enabled.

As a side note, it is always better to click() a hyperlink, so:

```
currentPage = anchors.get(0).click();
```

instead of

```
currentPage = (HtmlPage) browser.getPage(anchors.get(0).getHrefAttribute());
```